# jqRangeSlider slow on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `jqRangeSlider` in creating multiple instances on my website.
For some reason, and only on `Chrome` - it takes a lot of time to render the sliders (about 1.5-2 seconds each X 9). The sliders also move very slowly (again, only `chrome`).
`FF` and `IE` are working perfectly.

I tried removing other JS files, but for no avail. I'm not even sure how to debug such a problem.

Would really appreciate any idea.

Comment: Do you have some code to share? Your page with the issue, a jsfiddle or jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found the bug.
The issue originated, oddly enough, from a direction:rtl css property on the body element :\
Now works, as usual, faster than FF and IE.
Hope this will help someone.